# Run server alongside infinite loop in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, loops

I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import StringIO
import subprocess
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime
from PIL import Image

# Original code written by brainflakes and modified to exit
# image scanning for loop as soon as the sensitivity value is exceeded.
# this can speed taking of larger photo if motion detected early in scan

# Motion detection settings:
# need future changes to read values dynamically via command line parameter or xml file
# --------------------------
# Threshold      - (how much a pixel has to change by to be marked as "changed")
# Sensitivity    - (how many changed pixels before capturing an image) needs to be higher if noisy view
# ForceCapture   - (whether to force an image to be captured every forceCaptureTime seconds)
# filepath       - location of folder to save photos
# filenamePrefix - string that prefixes the file name for easier identification of files.
threshold = 10
sensitivity = 180
forceCapture = True
forceCaptureTime = 60 * 60 # Once an hour
filepath = "/home/pi/camera"
filenamePrefix = "capture"
# File photo size settings
saveWidth = 1280
saveHeight = 960
diskSpaceToReserve = 40 * 1024 * 1024 # Keep 40 mb free on disk

# Capture a small test image (for motion detection)
def captureTestImage():
    command = "raspistill -w %s -h %s -t 500 -e bmp -o -" % (100, 75)
    imageData = StringIO.StringIO()
    imageData.write(subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True))
    imageData.seek(0)
    im = Image.open(imageData)
    buffer = im.load()
    imageData.close()
    return im, buffer

# Save a full size image to disk
def saveImage(width, height, diskSpaceToReserve):
    keepDiskSpaceFree(diskSpaceToReserve)
    time = datetime.now()
    filename = filepath + "/" + filenamePrefix + "-%04d%02d%02d-%02d%02d%02d.jpg" % ( time.year, time.month, time.day, time.hour, time.minute, time.second)
    subprocess.call("raspistill -w 1296 -h 972 -t 1000 -e jpg -q 15 -o %s" % filename, shell=True)
    print "Captured %s" % filename

# Keep free space above given level
def keepDiskSpaceFree(bytesToReserve):
    if (getFreeSpace() < bytesToReserve):
        for filename in sorted(os.listdir(filepath + "/")):
            if filename.startswith(filenamePrefix) and filename.endswith(".jpg"):
                os.remove(filepath + "/" + filename)
                print "Deleted %s to avoid filling disk" % filename
                if (getFreeSpace() > bytesToReserve):
                    return

# Get available disk space
def getFreeSpace():
    st = os.statvfs(".")
    du = st.f_bavail * st.f_frsize
    return du

# Get first image
image1, buffer1 = captureTestImage()

# Reset last capture time
lastCapture = time.time()

# added this to give visual feedback of camera motion capture activity.  Can be removed as required
os.system('clear')
print "            Motion Detection Started"
print "            ------------------------"
print "Pixel Threshold (How much)   = " + str(threshold)
print "Sensitivity (changed Pixels) = " + str(sensitivity)
print "File Path for Image Save     = " + filepath
print "---------- Motion Capture File Activity --------------"

while (True):

    # Get comparison image
    image2, buffer2 = captureTestImage()

    # Count changed pixels
    changedPixels = 0
    for x in xrange(0, 100):
        # Scan one line of image then check sensitivity for movement
        for y in xrange(0, 75):
            # Just check green channel as it's the highest quality channel
            pixdiff = abs(buffer1[x,y][1] - buffer2[x,y][1])
            if pixdiff > threshold:
                changedPixels += 1

        # Changed logic - If movement sensitivity exceeded then
        # Save image and Exit before full image scan complete
        if changedPixels > sensitivity:   
            lastCapture = time.time()
            saveImage(saveWidth, saveHeight, diskSpaceToReserve)
            break
        continue

    # Check force capture
    if forceCapture:
        if time.time() - lastCapture > forceCaptureTime:
            changedPixels = sensitivity + 1

    # Swap comparison buffers
    image1  = image2
    buffer1 = buffer2
```

This code takes a picture once movement is detected, and keeps doing so until I manually stop it. (I should mention that the code is for use with the Raspberry Pi computer)

I also have the following code courtesy of Nathan Jhaveri here on Stackoverflow:

```
import SocketServer
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler

def some_function():
    print "some_function got called"

class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/captureImage':
            saveImage(saveWidth, saveHeight, diskSpaceToReserve)

        self.send_response(200)

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", 8080), MyHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

This code runs a simple server that would execute the

```
saveImage(saveWidth, saveHeight, diskSpaceToReserve)
```

function when the url /captureImage is visited on the server. I have run into a problem with this though. Since the two pieces of code are both infinite loops, they cannot run side by side. I would assume I need to do some kind of multi-threading, but that is something I have never experimented with in Python before. I would appreciate if anyone could help me get back on track with this.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a small question. Your best bet is to work through some python threading tutorials such as this one: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm (found via google)

Answer (score 0):

Try taking the webserver, and running it on a background thread so that calling "serve_forever()" does not block the main thread's "while True:" loop.  Replace the existing call to httpd.serve_forever() with something like:

```
import threading
class WebThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", 8080), MyHandler)
        httpd.serve_forever()

WebThread().start()
```

Make sure that chunk of code runs before the "while (True):" loop, and you should have both the webserver loop and the main thread loop running.

Keep in mind that having multiple threads can get complicated.  What happens when two threads access the same resource at the same time? As Velox mentioned in another answer, it is worthwhile to learn more about threading.

Answer (score 0):

I can illustrate a simple example using multi-threading.

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import concurrent.futures
import logging
import time

hostName = "localhost"
serverPort = 5001

class MyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<html><head><title>python3 http server</title><body>", "utf-8"))  

def serverThread():
    webServer = HTTPServer((hostName, serverPort), MyServer)
    logging.info("Server started http://%s:%s" % (hostName, serverPort))

    try:
        webServer.serve_forever()
    except :
        pass

    webServer.server_close()
    logging.info("Server stopped.")
  
def logThread():
    while True:
        time.sleep(2.0)
        logging.info('hi from log thread')

if __name__ == "__main__":        

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
       
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
        # Run Server
        executor.submit(serverThread)
        # Run A Parallel Thread
        executor.submit(logThread)
```

Here we have two threads : **A server** and **Another parallel Thread** which logs a line every 2 seconds.

You have to define code corresponding to each thread in separate functions, and submit it to the **concurrent.futures** Thread Pool.

*Btw, I have not done study of how efficient it is to run a server this way.*