# Reading a Linux system file using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, linux, firefox

I'm trying to update a page of mine which currently does not have a way to refresh the version number that is read from a file because the page is only generated once by a Python script. I decided to convert the page to a static page rather than a generated one and try to just read the information using JavaScript. The problem is that two of the files I need to read are **/proc/cpuinfo** and **/proc/device-tree/model**. The files are server-side.

I can't seem to find any information on using `FileReader` with just a file path, and it seems to rely on the "file" input to provide a `File` object. I looked into using `XMLHttpRequest`, but would that even be able to read a file that is not under **/var/www**?

The reason the Python script was able to read the files is because it is a cgi script and has sudo permissions.

Do I have any options to do this with a static HTML page? Or will I need to keep the page generator script since those two files live outside the **/var/www** directory?

Comment: Perhaps you can symlink them under `/var/www`? If the server is set up to follow symlinks, `XMLHttpRequest` should be able to fetch them

Answer (score 4):

Your static page cannot access the server using JavaScript directly. That would be a huge security hole. Because I can run JavaScript myself on your page simply by opening the developer tools. Something has to run on the server in response to a request from your webpage, and return that information.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of generating a full page with the version number embedded in the page with phyton, generate with phyton a response containing only the version number and than require that from javascript with XMLHttpRequest (see ajax)

Comment: This is probably the direction I was going to take because I didn't expect I'd be able to access **/proc** from JavaScript, but how do I return information from the Python script to the ajax callback function?

Comment: Through some searching, it seems like the only way to handle GET requests and return data back to the calling JavaScript is to use a framework like Flask, and I don't want to have to implement that just to retrieve 2 lines of information... there has to be a simpler way.

Comment: @DarinBeaudreau you shouldn't need an entire framework just to respond to a GET request. Example at this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434947/python-respond-to-http-request