# How store query string

Tags: python, python-2.7, url

I am trying to store an incoming url -- including query string -- in a Python 2.7 application as a simple variable, you could call it var. The url is being passed into httpd 2.4.6 and I want the app to capture this url. Can someone suggest a way to do this? Something like "requests" but the app listens always for incoming requests to httpd and captures them in a variable or a list.

The query string would be passed as arguments to another process. That part of the app is done.

The app and the httpd service both run on same server.

This is difficult to search for on google. Was hoping someone could point the way.

Comment: It might help to post the code you have so far that's receiving the URL.

Comment: dont know how to start

Comment: this prob what i'm looking for:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434947/python-respond-to-http-request